# On Visualforce page i want to display INLINE EDIT function

Tags: visualforce

I need Inline edit function on single row  by using visualforce. For example i have one row with two buttons are EDIT/DELETE i want to edit on that button that will be display on entire row.

Comment: I've used the technique described by Adam. There is a fairly old blog post [here](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2009/04/an-approach-to-inplace-editing-with-visuaforce.html) with sample code explaining the technique.

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad question so I'll answer it broadly. A good pattern to get this done is the following:

- Create a wrapper class that has an action method for your edit buttons
- In constructor of wrapper class pass in SObject type that you are editing
- Create a list of instances of this wrapper class in your main controller class
- Create an apex:pageBlockTable that uses this list as its data

From here you know which item or edit button was clicked and can toggle the appropriate "edit state" values for them. For example, you could have a separate set of apex:inputText controls on the page that become visible when you click edit AND know the specific line you are editing from the command button / action function that set them.

Or more simply, just turn on inline editing for the standard or custom object and create an appropriate page layout to suit your needs. No coding needed.